# injectivity for $Id-T $ when $\limsup\limits_{\|x\|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|}<1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ an operator (not linear), if $\limsup\limits_{\|x\|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|}<1$, is it $Id-T$ one to one ?

Comment: Why should it be? Locally, your $T$ can be arbitrary, since your condition only says something for very large $x$. For example, you condition holds for every bounded $T$, in the sense that $\|T x\| \leq C$ for all $x$.

Comment: you means that if $\limsup\limits_{\|x\|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|}<1$ and $\|Tx\| \leq C$ for all $x$ , then $I-T$ is one to one ? why ?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the comment by PhoemueX: Take $T : X \to X$ defined via
$$
T(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } \|x\| \le 1, \\ x / \|x\| & \text{if } \|x\| > 1.\end{cases}$$
Then, $T$ satisfies your condition, but $\mathrm{Id} - T$ is not injective.